# How to get the 8 high bits of a 16-bit variable?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, avr

I'm doing some AVR programming and am kinda getting to grips with this whole bit operation thing but still ain't so sure about data type conversion.

For example:

I have a 16-bit variable (`myValue`) that corresponds the state of 16 LEDs over 2 ports (e.g. 8 LEDs on Port A and 8 on Port D). The 8 high bits of `myValue` are on Port D.

So my idea was to essentially use `(0b0000000011111111 & myValue)` to get the values for Port A and `(0b1111111100000000 & myValue)` for Port D

The question is then can I then do something like `uint8_t portA = (0b0000000011111111 & myValue)`? I believe I can just simply then set

```
PORTA |= portA
```

since Port A has only 8 pins (in my case).

The problem arises in Port D since using unsigned 8 bit on the other hand is not possible for Port D because it will still remain a 16-bit variable after the `&` operation? How do I then set an 8-pin Port D with a 16-bit variable?

Comment: As a super-minor stylistic point, I think most C programmers would write it as `myValue & 0xff`, i.e. the variable goes first, the constant (often referred to as "the mask") is the second argument. Also note that binary literals (`0b...`) are not part of standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
PORTD = (myValue >> 8) & 0xff;
```

Also stay on the safe side and do the clipping for port A:

```
PORTA = myValue & 0xff;
```

Be aware that by using `|=` you can only set bits from 0 to 1, bits that are already 1 will not be altered by the or operation.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a value with a larger size than the destination will *truncate* the high bits. So just

```
PORTA = (uint8_t)myValue;
```

is enough, no need for an `AND`.

Likewise for port D you can use

```
PORTD = (uint8_t)(myValue >> 8);
```

The casts here are unnecessary. They're just for disabling compiler warning in some cases, and also for clarity

Note that you should **directly assign the value** if you want to copy values from `myValue`. Using `OR` will need a read to load the current port's value, `OR` it with the mask and then write it back, which is slower than a mere copy. Doing logic on the values is only needed when you just want to **adjust *some* bits** of the port

Comment: I think this is a little bit cleaner than the accepted answer. The explicit cast is as redundant as the 0xff, but it shows in a cleaner way what data type the programmer was expecting on the left side of the assignment.